# How many hats have been featured from the beginning up to & including Bash 2015?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I've been through several events on SF&F. Futurama had its fleeting moment in the Sun, but Winter Bash has become a recurring event.

How many hat designs have been featured in the Winter Bash contests from the beginning up to & including the current 2015 edition?

Answer (score 9):

Um... a lot? Well over a hundred. Here are some numbers by year:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║    Year     ║ Regular ║ Secret ║  Total  ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 2011*       ║      35 ║     0  ║      35 ║
║ 2012        ║      27 ║     7  ║      34 ║
║ 2013        ║      35 ║    10  ║      45 ║
║ 2014        ║      31 ║     8  ║      39 ║
║ 2015        ║      28 ║ 13/14  ║   41/42 ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ WB total*   ║     121 ║ 38/39  ║ 159/160 ║
║ Grand total ║     156 ║ 38/39  ║ 194/195 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Why is there an uncertain number after 2015? Because you can argue about whether Flip Flop counts as one hat or two.

In five years, we've never had a repeat design... we came *really close* with 2014's Eureka, which had the exact same trigger as 2013's Eureka (and this year's Archimedes... get it?) and the same art theme, but I looked really closely and there is a subtle difference between the two drawings.

*: technically, 2011 didn't have a Winter Bash. It was the year of [Hat Dash](https://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash), the Arqade special event that led to Winter Bash.

Comment: +3, -2, +4 - so this year I expect 12 secret hats.

Comment: @Sha I think 18, or 22. Who is closer, Pops?

Comment: @nicael it's a secret!

Comment: @Sha obvioulsy it is! I didn't ask Pops to answer there ;)

Comment: "I didn't ask to get an answer". Typical meta here.

Comment: @nicael well, I won. What do I get? ;)